# Importing a Python script that requires system arguments into unit test

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have a Python file, let's call it script1.py. I am trying to write a unit test (using unittest) called script1_test.py. script1 is meant to be called from command line and take in a number of arguments. When script 1 is run, it starts off with:

```
if __name__ == "__main__" and len(sys.argv) == 6:
    func1()
else
   print "Wrong number of arguments"
   sys.exit(1)
```

I'm just trying to execute and test a function (here called func1) within script1
 independent of the main body of the code. But when I do so, I keep hitting the sys.exit from main during the import phase. How can I run the test without hitting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do the import of your script, `__name__` is not equal to main so you're calling the `else` block. Instead you should nest your `if` blocks:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) == 6:
       func1()
    else:
       print "Wrong number of arguments"
       sys.exit(1)
```